# setting up a unique column in mysql and showing flashdata in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have a codeigniter website, where i have a unique column, users are asked to insert data using input fields, if a user tries to add dupliate value in the column by default the datas wont be inserted, so i am trying to set flash data according to it:

```php
function import_domestic_excel_data(){

if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])){
   $path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
   $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
   foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet){
       $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
       $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
       for($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++){
 $sendername = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();
 $senderreference = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
  if(!empty($sendername)){
               $data[] = array(
                   'sendername'  => $sendername,
                   'senderreference'   => $senderreference,
               );
           }
}
       $response=$this->excel_import_model->insert_excel($data);
   if($response){
    $this->session->set_flashdata("Success","Data Added Successfully !");
    redirect('listconsignment' , 'refresh');
}
  else{
   $this->session->set_flashdata("Error","Data Upload Error !");
    redirect('listconsignment' , 'refresh');
  }
 }
 
}
}
```

now here the problem is, whatever the outcome like if the data gets uploaded or if the data doesnt get uploaded am only getting the error message set in flashdata, not only flashdata, i tried simply echoing "error" and "success", then also its echoing error if the data is successfully uploaded. can anyone please tell me what could be wrong in here. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you put the `set_flashdata` inside `foreach`:

```
foreach ($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
   ...
}
```

Maybe there will be always a `$response = false` on the last `$worksheet` of the loop. So it will always error to the session. Take the block to check $response outside foreach will solve this problem:

```
$result = false;
foreach ($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    ....
    $response = $this->excel_import_model->insert_excel($data);
    if ($response) {
        $result = true; // Change to condition to set true to what you want
    }
}
if($result){
    $this->session->set_flashdata("Success", "Data Added Successfully !");
    redirect('listconsignment', 'refresh');
}
else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata("Error", "Data Upload Error !");
    redirect('listconsignment', 'refresh');
}
```

Comment: tried bro, same error. only data upload error flash is coming

Comment: Could you `echo $result` to make sure it's right value

Comment: And make sure you get the value out of session the right way, for example: `$this->session->flashdata('Success');` I think if you simply echo "error" and "success" but it didn't work maybe the way you get session value has something wrong